# Make Angular router parent not active when it children are active

Tags: angular, router, angular-router

I have a navbar as a router, with two anchor tags, Home and Create, Create being a child of Home. I want to make the Create anchor tag active when it is selected, but the Home anchor also gets active as it is the parent of Create.

Is there any way of preventing the parent anchor tag to get active when it children are?

**Home.component**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li [routerLink]="'/home'" routerLinkActive="active">
       <a>Home</a>
   </li>
   <li [routerLink]="'create'" routerLinkActive="active">
       <a>Create</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**app.routing**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: "home", component: HomeComponent, children: [{
        path: "create", component: CreateComponent
    }]
}];
```

**Current behaviour**

Accessing /home (notice only home anchor tag is active): 
[image]

Accessing /home/create (notice both anchor tags are active)[image]

**Wanted behaviour**

Accessing /home (notice only home anchor tag is active): 
[image]

Accessing /home/create (notice only create tag is active):[image]

Am I missing something in the home component or is it a normal behaviour and I shouldn't use Create as a child of Home?

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: use routerLinkActiveOptions https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Comment: Damn, that was easier than I thought, don't know how I didn't come across this in the docs earlier, thanks for pointint it out. I managed to make it work, if you want, you can reply with a more detailed answer with some code and I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add: `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"`

Comment: This worked, as Eliseo pointed out correclty, this can be found in the docs. Don't know how I didn't find it honestly, thanks for the code, I'll accept the anser :)

Comment: Thanks I missed this in the documentation too, I will add it here for reference.
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#routerLinkActiveOptions